# Join string with same property using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model like below

```
public class PropsModel
{
    public int props_id { get; set; }
    public string props_name { get; set; }
    public int props_order { get; set; }
}
```

Sample values

```
[
   { 1, "red" ,0 }
   { 2, "green", 3}
   { 1, "light red" ,1 }
   { 3, "yellow", 2}
   { 2, "blue", 6}    
]
```

Result STRING  :  **"red/light red" , "yellow"  ,  "green/blue"**

Output string rules

- Separate strings with the same id by / (Example:  "red/light red") and then comma separate all combined strings with Props_Order value

Current implementation

```
    List<string> _inflections = new List<string>();
    var distinctIDs = inflections_model.Select(x => x.form_id).Distinct(); //find distinct IDs
    foreach (int _id in distinctIDs) //for each distinct ID , join the string  to LIST
    {
     string inflection_val = string.Join(" / ", from item in inflections_model 
                                                      where item.form_id==_id
                                                      select item.props_name );
        _inflections.Add(inflection_val);
    }
    string inflection_string = string.Join(", ", _inflections);  //combine processed STRINGS to a comma separate list
```

This produces needed result , but not in the order  (props_order is not used anywhere).

Can we make this to a single LINQ query?

Comment: confused which one should be selected as the answer from below comments,  Few of them returns the same result and requesting readers to use the optimal solution for them

Comment: Just pick the first one that suited you, otherwise people will keep posting answers as is happening now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use LINQ GroupBy and Select:

```
var data = inflections_model.GroupBy(p=> p.props_id) // this gives you groups
  .Select(g =>  
      String.Join("/", g.OrderBy(r=>r.props_order)
                        .Select(r=>r.props_name)))  
var inflection_string = string.Join(", ",data)
```

Comment: r=>props_order doesnt exists in current context

Answer (score 2):

This orders the groups of elements based on the lowest value of `props_order` in each group

```
string.Join(", ",
    inflections_model
        .GroupBy(o => o.props_id)
        .OrderBy(g => g.Min(o => o.props_order))
        .Select(g => string.Join("/", g.Select(o => o.props_name))));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to `GroupBy` items props_id and `OrderBy` props_order as following one single LINQ:

```
    var _inflections = inflections_model.OrderBy(o => o.props_order)
                                                .GroupBy(i => i.props_id)
                                                .Select(s => String.Join("/", s.Select(p => p.props_name)));

    var inflection_string = String.Join(",", _inflections);
```

It will give following result as desired:

> "red/light red","yellow","green/blue"

Comment: even you get sorted output,  `GroupBy` does not guarantee that order will be preserved. It works for LINQ2Objects but it will not work for SQL for example. `OrderBy` and then `GroupBy` is misleading and tricky.  It will be better to order by `props_order` the group itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below implementation

```
var groups = list.GroupBy(x => x.props_id); //Group By Id

List<string> stringList = new List<string>(); //stringList to store common records with /
foreach(var grp in groups)
    stringList.Add(string.Join("/", list.Where(x => x.props_id == grp.Key).Select(y => y.props_name)));  //Logic to select property names from common groups

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", stringList)); //Print result
```

Output:

```
red/light red, green/blue, Yellow
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/c4yOsK)

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = models.OrderBy(x => x.props_order).ToLookup(x => x.props_id, x => x.props_name).Select(name => string.Join("/", name));
var result = string.Join(",", list);
```

Prints

> "red/light red,yellow,green/blue"

Better performance with **Lookup**

**On machine,**

GroupBy => takes 1.6215 milliseconds

Lookup => takes 0.2072 milliseconds